# Chemical Formula with Subscriptions

Tags: conditional-formatting

I am building a spreadsheet with column headings including Chemical Name, CAS# and Chemical Formula. I would like to format the Chemical Formula so that when entered the numbers on the formula are automatically subscripted.

Comment: So what do you expect us to do to help you? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You need to write a VBA script that does the following. Whenever a cell changes value within a target range, then each character in the cell should be evaluated to determine whether it is a letter or number. If it is a number, then format it as a subscript. If you can work up a script, hopefully someone here can help you to refine it. This link contains a reply on how to start something similar: `https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/run-vba-when-exiting-a-cell/d1569a4a-4d8d-40b4-8fa1-c7fb97fe9844`

Comment: This is a much better link: `https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3759-excel-find-and-replace-subscript.html`

Comment: Not all numbers in a formula are subscripts, e.g. gypsum, CaSO4· **2** H2O. all should be subscript, except for that denoting two water molecules. Another example, methane hydrate (clathrate): **8** CH4· **46** H2O

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik, good point. If the user were to insert a dot (or plus) before a coefficient, the script could be modified to look at the preceding character and if a dot (or plus) or if the preceding character is a non-subscript number, then do not apply subscript formatting to the current number. That is, subscript formatting would only be applied if the character is not a leading number, the preceding character is a letter, or the preceding character is a number with subscript formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3759-excel-find-and-replace-subscript.html

---

### Excel VBA Script

```
Sub SubscriptNumbers()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20160705
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xChar As String
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
    xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xTxt = xCell.Value
        For I = 1 To Len(xTxt)
            xChar = Mid(xTxt, I, 1)
            If xChar >= "0" And xChar <= "9" Then
                xCell.Characters(I, 1).Font.Subscript = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Brian,  thank you! This did it.  I wasn't worried about any potential mixups as my formula were all Alkanes so every number would be a subscript!

Comment: Thank you. Please mark as an answer if it solved your problem.